# How do I create an executable jar for my webapp with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

**Backgound**
I develop a webapp using a REST Interface with Spring. Normally I develop and execute my software with Eclipse. When my program has been started I enter localhost:8080/RESTPath in Chrome to access RESTPath with my program.

**Issue**
Now I want to build and execute my program with Maven instead with a executeble jar. The issue is that my knowledge with Maven is limited so I'm not sure how to do. Of course I have googled my issue and I have tested some examples but without succes. So far I think I should use the plugin tomcat7-maven-plugin in my POM.xml to generate a jar to execute with *java -jar file.jar*. I have followed the example with a webapp using tomcat7-maven-plugin but the jar file is never generated: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven.

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <!-- My project -->
    <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>stocks-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    
    <!-- My projects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stocks_Backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Other</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

**Question**
how should my POM look like a how should I build with Maven (i.e. *mvn clean compile*) to create an executable jar?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You are missing build section in your pom. When you execute `mvn clean package` you will get the JAR File in the target folder

Comment: I guess I must use the plugin tomcat7-maven-plugin because I haven't a Tomcat server installed so it must be embedded with my webapp. Your suggested plugin does not embedd Tomcat.

Comment: you have spring-boot-starter-web in your pom as dependency. In this case the embedded tomcat is already in there.  If you will make a package you can run java -jar <jar-file> and the embedded tomcat starts